# finite sequences,linear order, lexicographic order, well order, cardinal

Tags: order-theory, ordinals

Let $\lambda$ be an infinite cardinal.Consider the lexicographic order on $\lambda^{< \omega}$. Why this order is not a well-order: how may an infinite long descending chain look like? Why every descending chain is of order type at most $\omega$? Is it true that in lexicographic order a shorter sequence precedes a longer one, and then the order of these two is decided componentwise ?

Comment: Lexicographic order is componentwise without regard to length, so azz precedes b.  Length only comes in if we go through all the letters in one string, so abc precedes abcd.

Comment: The question is *really* about $\lambda$ being an infinite ordinal, not a cardinal. So I changed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The [lexicographic order $\preceq$ on sequences of various lengths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Ordering_of_sequences_of_various_lengths) is indeed defined in such a way that if $\sigma$ is an initial segment of $\tau$, then $\sigma\preceq\tau$, and in all other cases the order is decided by the first position at which $\sigma$ and $\tau$ differ. That is not why there is an infinite descending chain in $\lambda^{<\omega}$, however: none of the sequences in the following chain is an initial segment of any of the others.

$$1\succ01\succ001\succ0001\succ00001\succ\ldots$$

With this as a model you should be able to form many other infinite descending chains.

It’s not true that every descending chain is of order type at most $\omega$. Consider the descending chain

$$2\succ12\succ112\succ1112\succ11112\succ\ldots$$

of order type $\omega$; can you find a way to extend it to a descending chain of type $\omega+1$? How about $\omega+\omega$?

Comment: I can now create a descending chain of type $\omega+\omega$.What about $\omega^{\omega}$?And what about type $\epsilon_0$?Is it true that the length of such descending chains is cofinal in and bounded by $\omega_1$ which is, moreover, not attained?

Comment: @user3357120: Off the top of my head I’m not sure, and I’ve not yet had time to think seriously about it. I intend to give it some serious thought later today, but you might want to ask it as a separate question (with a link to this one).

Comment: @user3357120: So far I can get $\omega^2\cdot n$ for $n\in\omega$.

Comment: How?I can get $\omega^n$ for $n\in \omega$.

Comment: @user3357120: Here’s $\omega^2$: $$\begin{align*}&1\succ02\succ013\succ0124\succ01235\succ\ldots\\&\succ01\succ002\succ0013\succ00124\succ001235\succ\ldots\\&\succ001\succ0002\succ00013\succ000124\succ0001235\succ\ldots\\&\;\vdots\end{align*}\tag{A}$$ 

To get $\omega^2\cdot2$, add $1$ to each entry in $(1)$ and move the result ahead of $(1)$:

$$\begin{align*}&2\succ13\succ124\succ1235\succ12346\succ\ldots\\&\succ12\succ113\succ1124\succ11235\succ112346\succ\ldots\\&\succ112\succ1113\succ11124\succ111235\succ1112346\succ\ldots\\&\;\vdots\\&\succ(\text{A})\end{align*}$$

Comment: Where do we use that $\lambda$ is really infinite? We use only $n \in \omega$ so $\lambda=\omega$ suffices?! How $\lambda>\omega$ gives us more power in creating descending chains??

Comment: @user3357120: The lexicographic order on ${^{<\omega}\lambda}$ certainly depends on $\lambda$; I merely showed that as long as $\lambda\ge 2$, it’s not a well-order.

Comment: Yes, but regarding our aim to get a descending chain as of longest type as possible, does $\lambda>\omega$ help us in some way?

Comment: @user3357120: I don’t know; I’ve not thought further about it.

Comment: Please try to think in case of your (A) if continuing with infinite elements of finite sequences does give us longer chain then declared: $\omega^2$

Comment: Is this observation true: every step in (A) makes the finite sequence one member longer so it can never continue after $\omega$?

Comment: @user3357120: The $\omega^2$ sequence $(\text{A})$ can’t be extended more than a finite number of terms for an even simpler reason: the only finite sequences that precede all of the finite sequences $1,01,001,0001,\ldots$ except $0$ sequences, and any descending chain of them is finite.